# Fetching API on nextjs 13 (app directory) error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from a headless CMS (strapi) but i keep getting the error
"Error: _hooks_useFetch__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function" in Data.js
can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my code here?

src/app/page.js

```
import React from "react";
import Data from "../ui/Data";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <Data />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

src/ui/Data.js

```
import ItemHomeUI from "./ItemHomeUI";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";

export default async function Data() {
  const data = await useFetch(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "?populate=*&filters[type][$eq]=trending"
  );
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        {data.map((item) => {
          return <ItemHomeUI item={item} key={item.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

src/hooks/useFetch.js

```
async function useFetch(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("failed");
  }
  return res.json();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename the `useFetch` function to differentiate it with from a custom hook, as server components don't support hooks.

src/ui/Data.js

```
import ItemHomeUI from "./ItemHomeUI";

async function fetchData(url) {
 const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("failed");
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Data() {
  const data = await fetchData(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "?populate=*&filters[type][$eq]=trending"
  );
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        {data.map((item) => {
          return <ItemHomeUI item={item} key={item.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```